# Spring MVC 3 ModelAndView: controller method to return several views

Tags: spring-mvc, modelandview

my requirement is to return view according to the selected value (select form)

view.jsp:

```
      <form  method="post" action="/aaa">
                      <select id="attr1" name="attr1">

                            <option value="1">A</option>
                            <option value="2">B</option>

                        </select>
                  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

if the value selected is A(1) is selected, view1 is the view to display, else view2 is displayed.

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/aaa", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndview methodName ( HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response){

   attribute=request.getParameter("attr1");

   if (attribute==1) return new ModelAndView("view1")
   else if (attribute==2) return new ModelAndView ("view2")

   }
```

How can I do it? 
Thanks.

Comment: You have tons of syntax errors. Also, one thing is missing: If `1`, then `view1`. If `2`, then `view2`. What if **not** `1` or `2`? What view should it be?

Comment: thnk you for reply, this is just the logic of the method :), I have just 2 views to displaying( view1 if 1 is selected, view2 if 2 is selected)

Comment: @acdcjunior asked you what if nothing is selected... .

Comment: Yeah, but your logic says **if attr=1 then view1; else if attr=2 then view2 else viewWHAT?"**

Comment: I got an error when I return 2 ModelAndView, so my logic is wrong

Comment: nothing, I must choose one

Comment: What if he posts while the selected value is `--select type--`? Then attr will be `NONE`. What view should be returned? `view1`? What's the "default" view?

Comment: if nothing is selected, i saty in the same page

Comment: <select id="attr1" name="attr1">

                            <option value="1">A</option>
                            <option value="2">B</option>

                        </select>

Comment: Unless you send in the `POST` request what view the user is hitting from, such information (what view was the user in) is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple views are perfectly possible.

Considering the HTML:

```
<select id="attr1" name="attr1">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
</select>
```

Then the controller method should be:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/aaa", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView methodName(@RequestParam(value = "attr1") int attribute) {
    if (attribute == 1) {
        return new ModelAndView("view1");
    }
    else if (attribute == 2) {
        return new ModelAndView("view2");
    }
    else {
        return null; // Empty 200 OK just to be sure if other attr is received
    }
}
```

Comment: If you must use `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` let me know. The above answer is simpler though.

Comment: I use HttpServletRequest to get the parametrs from the view.

Comment: Yeah, `@RequestParam(value = "attr1") int attribute` maps automatically the param `attr1` to the variable `attribute`.

Comment: it's better, I get the value selected but no view displayed (404). I'm verifying may be I have some errors.. else I will ask!! :) thank you soooooo much.

Comment: Make sure the views `view1` and `view2` exist with those names. If there's something else I can do for you, just let me know...

Comment: hi, the 2 views works fine when i return just one of them,but not if i do like above

Comment: Probleme is that method return always null.  else {
        return null; 
    }

Comment: Ok, let me check what may be going on.

Comment: Your `action` attribute of the form may be incorrect. Where is your app deployed at? If it is deployed at, for instance, `http://localhost:8080/mySpringApp`, then the form action should be `<form  method="post" action="/mySpringApp/aaa">` - you have to put the full path there.

Comment: yes, it's correct, probleme is method always return the last condition, when I return another view instead of null, i get it when I submit.

Comment: I tried with this    ModelAndView mav= new ModelAndView();

  if (type==1) {
   mav=new ModelAndView("view1");
   
   }
  
  else if (attr==2) 
   {
   mav= new ModelAndView("view2");
   
   }
   return mav;  but nothing

Comment: What are the types of your `type` and `attr`? If they are strings, you must use `if (type.equals("1")` and `else if (attr.equals("2")`.

Comment: YESSS, ;) , they are a strings, really I apreciate your help, thank you so muchh friend.